# 'Mean' not working for Pandas DataFrame, reading from Pickle with 16 x 200,000+ observations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a pickle file which is 36.9 MB, it is a data file which contains 16 variables with 239,427 observations.

(I actually have a number of other pickle files each with 16 variables varying from 6.8 MB to 36.9 MB based on number of observations. But I only seem to have a problem with the largest file...which leads me to believe it might be that the file is too large...)

I am using Pandas in Python to read to the pickle, as so:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('filename.pickle')
```

I am interested in the descriptive statistics for this DataFrame. So I use the pandas DataFrame describe function, as so:

```
df.describe()
```

The function works for all my pickle files and as an output I get the 'count' , 'mean', 'std', 'min', 'max', ...etc.

However, if I try to use the 'mean' function on the DataFrame from the largest pickle file, as so:

```
df.mean()
```

My Python notebook spends a long time "busy" and then seems to timeout.

Can anyone help me to understand why this might be the case? I am very confused.

It seems that the std function does work just fine:

```
df.std()
```

Ultimately, I want to calculate the relative standard deviation for each variable (so I need the mean and std for each variable). And I plan to iterate through a list of DataFrames.

Comment: is it possible to upload the pickle file? it might also be data issue

Comment: What is the size of pickle file?

Comment: @hacker315 the pickle file is 37 MB

Comment: @aditya sorry I can't upload it right now

Comment: can you try to use other IDEs? or just run it in command line terminal outside of anyIDE?

Comment: @AdityaSantoso , I wrote the file to .csv & found there were a number of "NaN" data in the dataset. Once I removed the NaN data, it seemed to correct the problem. Weird that the .describe() works in this case but the .std() does not though...

Comment: @hamslice: which version of pandas do you use? In current version of pandas `std()` has a default argument of `skipna=True`
 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html

Comment: @AdityaSantoso Unfortunately I am very much limited by the corporate software policy of my employer. I am not running the latest versions ...  
  

- Python 3.4.1
- Anaconda 2.1.0
- Pandas 0.14.1

Comment: Odd. Even in pandas 0.14.1 the std() also has default `skipna=True` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html?highlight=std#pandas.DataFrame.std) . Maybe try supplying the argument explicitly?